# Azure Developer Tools for Visual Studio fails when VS installed on non c:\drive

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 installed on a non c:\ drive and it appears that the [Azure tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/azure-tools-vs.aspx) does not like this. When I attempt to create a new Cloud Azure Resource Group project then attempt to add a resource I get the following error.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I also notice that the JSON Outline Window does not populate when I view a resource template JSON file.

Other than installing VS on c:\ is there any way I can tweak something to get the Azure Resources tools to work properly?

Comment: Use https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx or try to run through WinDbg to at least find out which file it's complaining about.

Comment: Your easiest option is probably just to reinstall VS on the c drive.  Or you could try VS 2017

Comment: Reinstalling everything is what worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create an alias in the c:\ drive pointer to another drive such as:

```
mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0" "d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"
```

and then install Azure Developer Tools